# Failed to use truffle develop

Tags: truffle, ganache-cli, truffle-develop

When I successfully compiled and deployed contracts using Truffle and ganache-cli, I typed `truffle develop` to get into the `truffle(develop)>`, and then typed `let instance = await Factory.deployed()`, it then showed `Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://127.0.0.1:9545/.` But actually I have opened the new ganache-cli by the command  `ganache-cli -p 9545` (successfully run and showed `Listening on 127.0.0.1:9545`) before that.

Why this happened and what can I do?

Comment: You don't need to open both truffle develop and ganache-cli, most certainly when they are both configured to listen on the same port number.

Comment: However, after I successfully deploy contracts, I typed ```truffle develop``` and got into the ```truffle(develop)>```, and then typed ```let instance = await Factory.deployed()```, it then still showed ```Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://127.0.0.1:9545/.``` Though I didn't open the new window to typed ```ganache-cli -p 9545```, though I closed the only one ganache-cli (```ganache-cli --allowUnlimitedContractSize``` for deploying contracts) and then typed ```let instance = await Factory.deployed()```, it still showed that.

Comment: After starting the `Truffle'  check port (by default 7545).